# How do you properly persist what you type in a TextField or select in a dropdown in a drawer even when you swipe the drawer away?

Tags: flutter

I currently have a drawer with Textfields and a dropdown, when I type anything into the textfields or select something in the dropdown it stays there until I swipe the drawer away. I want what I type in the TextFields or select in the dropdown to stay there even when I swipe the drawer away. The drawer and the page the drawer is on are both stateful widgets. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

This is the drawer and it's TextFields and DropDown

```
class ItineraryDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItineraryDrawerState createState() => _ItineraryDrawerState();
}

class _ItineraryDrawerState extends State<ItineraryDrawer> {
  var stateList = states;
  String currentSelectedState;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .09,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Lorem Ipsum',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 70,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child:Container(
            //WRAPS ENTIRE SHEET
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.green],
                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                    stops: [0.1, 1])),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
            child: ListView( children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
                        height:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(12))),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _NameEditingController,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Name',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color:
                                Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 10),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
                        height:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(12))),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _CityEditingController,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'City',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color:
                                Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 10),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              stateDropDown(),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
                        height:
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .12,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(12))),
                        child: TextField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: _notesEditingController,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(12.0)),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Notes',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(105, 105, 105, 10),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
            ],),
          ), //WRAPS ENTIRE SHEET
        )
      ],);
  }
  stateDropDown() {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
              child: FormField<String>(
                builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white
                    ),
                    child: InputDecorator(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          hint: Text("Please Select a State or Province", style: 
                           TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                          value: currentSelectedState,
                          isDense: true,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              currentSelectedState = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: stateList.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )));
  }
}

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController _NameEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _CityEditingController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _notesEditingController = TextEditingController();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you want to persist that information only while the app is open or even after restarting the app. So if you want to persist only when the app is open, you should use a state management like BLoC (https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_pattern) or Provider (https://pub.dev/packages/provider), for example. And if you want to persist that information even when the user closes the app, you should use SharedPreferences (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) if you are not saving that much data or sqflite (https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) if you want to save lots of data;